# Software for video streaming

Tags: macos, video-streaming

In my organization, we have people at several locations in the US and abroad. For Lunch & Learn sessions, I sometimes download educational videos (Creative Commons License) and would like to broadcast them to participants at our other locations.

I have being using [GotoMeeting](http://www.gotomeeting.com/), but the results are poor -- the remote videos cannot keep up with the broadcast video, even though we have very fast Internet connections (50/20 at most locations).

Is there some software, either free or low cost, that I can install on my Mac (OS X 10.8.5) that will allow me to stream the videos, with me having control over pausing, etc. (I pause when when someone wants to discuss some aspect of the video)? All of the participants are on a VPN and can access my Mac's IP address.

I would rather not have to set up a whole web application to do this.

Although my preference is for Mac OS X software, Windows software will also work for me.

Comment: off-topic. Try http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`VLC media player`](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html) is a free tool on both Mac OSX and Windows which can broadcast a video stream. I have never used this function myself though, so I can't explain in detail how to use it.